# Am I right in my time complexity analysis for this algorithm?

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity, big-o

Long story short, I am looking to verify if my time complexity for following code is correct.

```
class Solution {
    public String reverseWords(String s) {
        int len = s.length(); int i=len-1, j=0;
        StringBuilder answer= new StringBuilder();
        while(i!=-1) {
            if(s.charAt(i)==' ') i--;
            else {
                j=i;
                while(j-1!=-1 && s.charAt(j-1)!=' ' ) j--; //j++;
                answer.append(s.substring(j, i+1)).append(' ');
                i=j-1;
            }
        }
        return answer.toString().trim(); //trim last index's space
    }
}
```

Constraints:

- `1 <= s.length <= 10^4`
- `s` contains English letters (upper-case and lower-case), digits, and spaces ' '.
- There is at least one word in `s`

Assuming string length is N.
My analysis is to further assume there are K spaces in string S and assume there are L different space separated words in it, as per given constraints we can conclude that L>=1 and K>=0.

Thus the average length of each word is N-K/L, outer loop runs thus, K+L times, and inner loop runs independent of outer for 2*(N-K)/L times making total complexity as 2(N-K)/L + K+L which is still  order of O(N).

Am I making any wrong assumptions? Is there a way to simplify this formula of 2*(N-K)/L + K+L

Comment: I haven't looked in detail, but my first thought is that you can/should probably analyze this simply in terms of *N*. *K* and *L* strike me as overcomplications.

Comment: If you do use *K* and *L* then you'll need to explain how you reduce 2(N-K)/L+K+L to O(N). Don't handwave that step.

Comment: If `N` is the number of characters in your `String s`, then the code walks through all those characters once. Hence the overall complexity would be simply `O(N)`. Getting rid of K and L would help you simplify this. In other words to relate with your assumptions, your outer loop iterate through each 'word' in the string, the inner loop iterates through each 'character' of those words. Effectively all characters of the input string `N`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman wouldnt k and l become significant when we have a string made up of single letters, separated by single spaces . basically when k=n/2 and l=n/2, so should we not account for that?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I am reducing them to O(N) simply cuz there is no quadratic term of input size N, hence asymptotic tightest bound can be taken as O(N) , or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the runtime is O(n).

Although I'm not too sure what the N in your formula is, the general rule for simplifying is looking at the largest value.
I will assume that N is the largest for you.
The "+K+L" is negligible so we have 2*(N-K)/L.
Distributing: (2/L)N - (2/L)K.
We drop constants and take the largest one so it would still be O(n)

In my opinion, an easier way to look at the runtime is to just look at how many times your code runs through the string. Your first while goes until it triggers the else. Starting from the index you stopped at, the second loop keeps counting until it stops. From there, you change the original i to the j and keep going through. I think the code looks at where i stops twice but that isn't enough to change the complexity (a fix would just be to set j to i - 1 since you know the char at i is not a space already).

As a short side note, N typically denotes the length of the input, whether it be string length or array size.

Comment: I am sorry i should have clarified,  N is the string length.

Comment: why would the K +L be negligible , when string is made up of  single letters, separated by spaces in the string. basically when k=n/2 and l=n/2

Comment: I guess we could write K and L in terms of N, but in that case we would just combine them with the first N, and the leading term would still disappear.